# Why is the plate small in the render result but normal looking in the view port?

Tags: rendering, scale

[image: Here is the viewport display.]

[image: Here is a render.]

I have tried aplying scale and none are parented to eachother.

Comment: Try to add your Blend file to get a quick answer

Comment: How do I add my blend file?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ upload the file, then **[edit]** your question and add the resulting link as part of the text.

Comment: maybe you've scaled and keyframed it, but yes please share your file so that we can check

Comment: I wonder if there are any modifiers that have different settings  for display and for render. But it is impossible to know with the current information in the question. Please edit your question and show images of the modifiers section of the properties window. Also, since it looks like you are following some "tutorial", you might learn more if you just watch the video over again and find where it is that you didn't follow the directions, and ended with this. At that point you can then write an answer to your own question, and hel others with a similar issue.